# Anylogic error during discrete event "execution class cannot be cast"

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I was trying to do a simulation of distribution center model using the tips from anylogic to our own, cause they work in similar ways but diferent products and warehouses, plus i just started with this program so i tried to fix every posible error during runtime cause i know it works slightly different from java programming so when i finally fix it this error happend and i dont know whats the root of it in the last modified archive. If i have to provide more codes let me know please

First one says:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
class com.anylogic.engine.Agent cannot be cast to class cocacola3.Muelle (com.anylogic.engine.Agent and cocacola3.Muelle are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at cocacola3.Main._OcuparMuelleDescarga_onSeizeUnit_xjal(Main.java:4908)
```

And the code with error is:

```
    
agent.muelle = (Muelle) unit;
agent.muelle.Ocupado = true;
DescargaEspera.add(agent);
verificarDescarga(); 
;
  }
  private void _hold_onEnter_xjal( final com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Hold<DescargaCamione> self, DescargaCamione agent ) {
    
self.block();
DescargaEspera.remove(agent); 
;
```

Images for context:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Me5fpTevvlWcZKMssEDhSaq9zaV3ncxH/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your `unit` is not an agent of type `Muelle`. It is as simple as that. Either make sure it is of type `Muelle` or change the type of the field `agent.muelle` to a more generic form such as `Agent` or `Object`.

You will probably want to do the former. If this happens in a `ResourcePool`, then make sure you tell it that the resources are of type `Muelle`